# Rails routing resource in namespace starting with a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 namespaces, api and v1
I have accounts and users as resources.

I want to map the routing as follows for all my resources:

/api/v1/:account_id/:resource/:id

i.e:
/api/v1/1/users/2

In the example 1 stands for account id and 2 stands for user id.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit obscure, it's difficult to understand what you're asking. I suggest that you edit your question to make it more understandable

Comment: What? I think it's pretty straight forward. I even gave an example. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I apologise, I stand corrected. The lack of formatting made me jump the gun a bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does away with namespaces, such that you don't need to append `API::V1::` to each controller, or bury view files in subdirectories. The following uses normal, top-level controllers and views:

```
scope '/api/v1/:id', :as => 'account' do
  resources :users
end
```

If you want to keep all the namespace structure stuff, do this:

```
namespace 'api' do
  namespace 'v1' do
    scope '/:id', :as => 'account' do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Something is happening, but now I get a uninitialized constant UsersController.

The idea was for the directory structre:
app
  - ws
    - v1
      - users_controller.rb

Doesn't seem to work like that. Is there any way I could use namespace instead of scope?

Noob questions, sorry, just started with rails and I'm forced by the Client to do it like this.

Comment: had to add...  to: 'api/v1/users'

Comment: Answer updated. Also, I am going off of your example. You need to replace `resources :users` with the resources you actually have.

Comment: Only new to rails, not programming in general :)

Comment: One more question, sorry, I'm getting a "Template is missing", obviously I don't have any templates, but I just want to return .json

Tried respond_to :json, doesn't seem to do the trick, am I missing something?

Comment: @CiprianTarta That should be it's own question, since it's outside the context of namespaced/scoped routes.