# Use a namespace only as param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

At the moment my routes are looking like this:

```
search_index GET   /search(.:format)     search#index
```

But I want to get routes like these:

```
search_index GET   /topic1/search(.:format)    search#index
search_index GET   /topic2/search(.:format)    search#index
```

As you can see, I don't want to introduce namespaces. The "topic" part of the url shall only be transported as a param.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails routing resource in namespace starting with a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606689/rails-routing-resource-in-namespace-starting-with-a-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your routes.rb append:

```
match '/:topic_name/search' => 'search#show', via: :get
```

this will add `topic_name` to your params, accessible in controller - `params[:topic_name]`